# Can I eliminate subqueries when calculating multiple aggregates in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm currently looking at a ratings database in SQLite 3.8.7.1 (Debian Jessie) and I'm having some diffculty getting the aggregates I want from a single query to return to a web app.

Dredging through my memories of SQL classes at uni and plenty of documentation, I've got a query that finds the total rating, plus positive and negative counts for each item being rated, but I'm not convinced I've got a sensible way of doing this, or that it's going to be particularly efficient.

The bare bones are on `sqlfiddle.com` as [`http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a71acb/1`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a71acb/1)

Essentially I have an item key, then the username of the person rating it, a language field currently set to `NULL` in all cases, date of the rating and either `1` or `-1` in the value field. I want to return a table of all items, with columns for number of positive ratings, number of negative ratings and overall rating (positive less negative).

Can I remove the subqueries somehow or make them more efficient? Are there alternative approaches I can pursue in SQLite?

Actually, my query returns a negative number for the total negative ratings; can I make this positive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal based on aggregate functions
on a foundation of a common table expression with a two-key `group-by`.

I changed the values of the negatives to be represented as a positive count,
but of course they are counted negative.
I also avoided the "NULL" entries, considering them ugly and it also makes sure that min/max return their side of 0, or 0.
Otherwise I believe the result is the desired output.

```
with subtotals(titem, subtotal) as 
(select item
      , sum(value) 
 from ratings
 group by item, value)
select titem as item
     , sum(subtotal) as total
     , max(0, max(subtotal)) as pos
     , -1*min(0, min(subtotal)) as neg
from subtotals
group by titem;
```

Output (`.width 20`, `.headers on`, `.mode columns`):

```
item                  total       pos         neg
--------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
africa                1           2           1
cant-buy-me-love      3           3           0
happy-together        -2          0           2
solitaire             0           1           1
```

You will probably count the common table expression as one sub-query, but it is only one.
Testing for speed meaningfully probably needs the full content of the database, not the small fiddle.